# How will i got the list of data from item node list using outer xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting request xml, in that xml i got the list of data from item node list, but i want only url of image as showing, so could anyone please help me how will i do this.

```
dr["ImageURL"] = xmlNode["media:content"].OuterXml;

<media:content url="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3912/15260624095_ef70d3ae3f_b.jpg"
               type="image/jpeg" 
               height="635" 
               width="1024" 
               xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" />
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: string xml = xmlNode["media:content"].OuterXml;
                    XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
                    doc1.LoadXml(xml);
                    XmlNodeList myItem1 = (XmlNodeList)doc1.GetElementsByTagName("media:content");

Comment: i tried this but not working properly, is there any way to replace all string and get only url string.

Comment: i got the idea.. string xml = xmlNode["media:content"].OuterXml;
                    string[] args = xml.Split(' ');


                    dr["ImageURL"] = args[1];

Comment: Please edit your original post with the additional information, rather than putting it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, then you have an XML-feed with a lot of nodes of the form:

```
<media:content url=".." type="…" height="…" width="…" xmlns:media="…" />
```

You could do something like this:

```
List<string> ImageUrlList = new List<string>();
XmlDocument MyXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
MyXmlDoc.Load("MyXmlFile.xml");
XmlNodeList MyNodeList = MyXmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("media:content");
foreach (XmlNode SingNode in MyNodeList) 
{   
   ImageUrlList.Add(SingNode.Attributes["url"].InnerText);
}
```